# How to randomly pick a vertices from graph?

Tags: c++, random, graph

I am looking for solution to pick a number randomly from graph using c++. 
For example I have a graph that add edge (one or more) between two vertices, how can I pick a number randomly?
some of code :

```
#include <iostream>
#include <list>
#include <queue>

using namespace std;
// Graph class represents a undirected graph using adjacency list representation
class Graph
{
private:
    int V; // # of vertices
    list<int> *adj;  // Pointer to an array containing adjacency lists
public:
    Graph(int V)  // Constructor
    {
        this->V = V;
        adj = new list<int>[V];
    }
    void addEdge(int v, int w); // function to add an edge to graph
    void print(int v, int w); //function to display 
    };

void Graph::addEdge(int v, int w)
{
    adj[v].push_front(w); // Add w to v’s list.
    adj[w].push_front(v); // Add v to w’s list.
    print(v, w);

}

void Graph::print(int v, int w) {
cout << v << " - " << w << endl;}
```

In the main:

```
Graph g(4);
    g.addEdge(0, 1);
    g.addEdge(0, 2);
    g.addEdge(1, 3);
```

Sample output:

> 0 - 1 
>  0 - 2 
>  1 - 3

Comment: Off-topic, but why are you using a bare c-style array for `adj`? Why not a `std::vector` or `std::array`? Then you wouldn't need to track the size manually with `V` or manually delete it.

Comment: @MarkH I'm working to add vertices using 'vector', so if there some hint how ?

Comment: Instead of `list<int> *adj`, you would use `vector< list<int> >`. Then, in the constructor, you would have `adj = vector< list<int> >(V)` to set the size of the vector. Better would be using an initializer list: `Graph(int V) : adj(V) {}`. Reference: http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/initializer_list

Comment: @MarkH how can change adj[v].push_front(w); ?

Comment: That line stays the same.

Comment: @MarkH I'm working to implementation a graph using vector, but dose not work !

Comment: `class Graph
{
private:
 int V; // # of vertices
 vector<list<int> > *adj;  // Pointer to an array containing adjacency lists
public:
 Graph(int V)  // Constructor
 {
  this->V = V;
  adj = new vector<list<int>>(V);
 }
 void addEdge(int v, int w); // function to add an edge to graph
 void print(int v, int w); //function to display 
};

void Graph::addEdge(int v, int w)
{
 adj[v].push_back(w);

 adj[w].push_back(v);

 print(v, w);

 

}`

Comment: The correct line is `adj = vector<list<int>>(V);`. Don't use `new`. The `vector` class automatically handles the array pointer. You don't need to do anything with `new` or `delete`. Also, you don't need `int V` as a member of Graph anymore. Just call `adj.size()` to get the number of vertices.

Comment: @MarkH it does not work !

Comment: Is there an error message?

Comment: The error: `adj = vector<int>(V);` and `adj[v].push_back(w);`

Comment: @MarkH first, no suitable conversion function from "std :: vector<int, std::allocatator<int>> to "std ::vector<<std::list<int,std::allocator<int>>, std:: allocator<std::list<int, std:: allocator<int>>>

Comment: @MarkH if you have a time can you write the right code!

Comment: it Work good when write this: `class Graph
{
private:
int V; // # of vertices
vector<list<int>> adj;  // Pointer to an array containing adjacency lists
public:
Graph(int V)  // Constructor
{
this->V = V;
adj = vector<list<int>>(V);
}
void addEdge(int v, int w); // function to add an edge to graph
void print(int v, int w); //function to display
};

void Graph::addEdge(int v, int w)
{
adj[v].push_back(w);

adj[w].push_back(v);

print(v, w);



}

void Graph::print(int v, int w) {
cout << v << " - " << w << endl;
}`

Comment: Your error was `adj = vector<int>(V);` where it should have been `adj = vector<list<int>>(V);`. I see you fixed that. Good.

Comment: @MarkH Do you have idea how can I pick a number randomly from vector graph (new code)?

Comment: Dean's answers below should point you in the right direction. `rand() % maxNumber` will get you a number from 0 to maxNumber-1.

Answer (score 0):

Use math lib. Rand function. Select random num and select (0 to number of edges-1) from list of edges, then select another random number and select that vertex of the edge, 0 or 1 (bottom/top vertex of edge)

Comment: Thanks! can you give to me more hint, please!

Comment: Add function ta access edges and vertexes of edges. then do this g.getRandEdge().getRandVertex()

Comment: You are storing edges in a pair form in a list so just do (total number of vertex in the list / 2 , take a random number between that and 0 and then times by 2 and then add a random number in the range of 0 or 1 to get either vertex

Answer (score 0):

```
#include <stdlib.h> 
#include <iostream>
#include <list>
#include <queue>

using namespace std;
// Graph class represents a undirected graph using adjacency list representation
class Graph
{
private:
    int V; // # of vertices
    list<int> *adj;  // Pointer to an array containing adjacency lists
public:
    Graph(int V)  // Constructor
    {
        this->V = V;
        adj = new list<int>[V];
    }
    void addEdge(int v, int w); // function to add an edge to graph
    void print(int v, int w); //function to display 
    };

void Graph::addEdge(int v, int w)
{
    adj[v].push_front(w); // Add w to v’s list.
    adj[w].push_front(v); // Add v to w’s list.
    print(v, w);

}

int Graph::getRandomVertexFromEdge()
{
    int list_size_divided_by_2 = adj.size() / 2;
    int rEdge = (rand() % list_size_divided_by_2);
    int rVW = (rand() % 1);
    int ret = adj[(rEdge + rVW)];
    //this will return a random vertex from a random edge;
    print(rEdge,rVW);
    return ret;
}

void Graph::print(int v, int w) {
cout << v << " - " << w << endl;}
```

Comment: @Bsh please see this untested implementation.

Comment: I'm testing now, but some error here (1- int list_size_divided_by_2 = adj.size() / 2; I corrected to adj[V].size()....) and  (2- int ret = adj[(rEdge + rVW)];) cannot covert from list type to int !

Comment: as i said, it is untested and provided as is, but it was only for you to grasp an understanding of how to do it.

Comment: as well, i did for get to times the rEdge var by 2 after the rand part,